# Moltin Cart with Laravel, adding more than one item

Tags: php, laravel-4, shopping-cart

I'm using Laravel and the Moltin laravel-cart package and have a question about it all works well but when I add more than one item the cart total updates but doesn't show the item.

I have the following which adds to the cart:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'cart']) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="path" value="{{ Request::path() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="{{ $item->image }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ $item->name }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="{{ $item->seo_description }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="{{ Session::get('size') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="colour" value="{{ Session::get('colour') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{ $item->price }}">
    @if ($item->stock > 0)
        <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Bag</button>
    @else
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Email us</a>
    @endif
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then I have this which shows the items of the carts.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <div class="media">
                <span class="thumbnail pull-left">
                    <img class="media-object" src="/uploads/product-images/{{$item->image}}" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;">
                </span>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        <a href="{{ $item->path }}">{{ $item->name }}</a>
                    </h4>
                    <span>Status: </span><span class="text-success"><strong>In Stock</strong></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="1">
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>&pound;{{ $item->price }}</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
    <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>&pound;{{ $item->price }}</strong></h5></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
    <td class="text-right"><h3><strong>&pound;{{ Cart::total(false) }}</strong></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="/remove/{{ $item->identifier }}" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/checkout" class="btn btn-success">
            Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But like I said it only shows one item, but yet the amount in £ is correct.

Comment: Anyone had the same problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to include the quantity for each item correctly. You have a line that's completely out of place inside your `@foreach`:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="1">
```

I think it should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->qty }}">
```

---

### EDIT

`Cart::insert()` doesn't increment the quantity, it just adds an item to the cart and overrides the quantity with the one specified. You need to check if the item is already in the cart when adding it and update the quantity accordingly. For that every item added to the cart must have a unique ID (so far I see you're setting `1` as the ID, which will not work because the cart uses the ID to differentiate between different products. So your code should look something like this:

```
public function add() {
    $input = Input::all();

    // Pass the product ID with the request parameters
    $id = $input['id'];

    // Try to get the cart item by ID
    $item = Cart::item($id)

    // If the result if false then the items was not found
    // in the cart and you need to create a new entry
    if ($item === false)
    {
        $product = array(
            'id'          => $id,
            'name'        => $input['product'],
            'price'       => $input['price'],
            'colour'      => $input['colour'],
            'quantity'    => $input['qty'],
            'image'       => $input['image'],
            'path'        => $input['path'],
            'description' => $input['description']
        );
    }
    else
    {
        // If it was found you just need to update the quantity
        $item->quantity += (int) $input['qty'];
        $product = $item;
    }

    Cart::insert($product);
    $items = Cart::contents();

    return View::make('cart.bag', compact('items'));
}
```

Comment: Even so that only still shows one in the table list.

Comment: I did a var_dump and only see one item even though there 3 in there.

Comment: Please post the code from your route/controller that's responsible for updating a cart item.

Comment: I only have this method:



 public function add()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $product = array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => $input['product'],
            'price' => $input['price'],
            'colour' => $input['colour'],
            'quantity' => $input['qty'],
            'image' => $input['image'],
            'path' => $input['path'],
            'description' => $input['description']
        );

        Cart::insert($product);
        $items = Cart::contents();

        return View::make('cart.bag', compact('items'));
    }

Comment: thats the part I needed $item->quantity += (int) $input['qty'];
        $product = $item;


thanks a bunch